# Finding the probability of an absolute value being lower than, using the central limit theorem.

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

So for example we're trying to find $P(|X -1| \le 0.6)$ with a mean $1$ and standard deviation $1$.

Using the teacher's advice, I've formatted the question to be

$P(|X -1| \le 0.6) = P(X -1 \le 0.6) + P(X -1 \ge -0.6)$

But my answer always seem to be wrong no matter where I go from here, any input about this?

Comment: Some description of the random variable $X$ would be useful.

Comment: @AndréNicolas ] Suppose X1, X2, · · · , X9, are identical, independent, exponential random variables, with f(x) = e^-x and n=9. Use the CLT to compute.

Comment: Actually, $P(|X-1|\leq .6) = P(X-1\leq .6)+P(X-1\leq -.60)$. You or your teacher made a mistake, because your inequality sign is facing the wrong direction in the second term.  Also, please use proper formatting. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: $\begin{align}\mathsf P(\lvert X-1\rvert\leq 0.6) ~=~& 1-\Big(\mathsf P(X-1<-0.6)+\mathsf P(X-1>0.6)\Big)\\[1ex] ~=~& \mathsf P(X-1\geq -0.6)+\mathsf P(X-1\leq 0.6) -1\\[1ex] ~=~& \mathsf P(X-1\leq 0.6)-\mathsf P(X-1\leq -0.6)\end{align}$

Comment: Also, you're supposed to include all relevant information, attempts and thoughts in the original post. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: You still have not described $X$, but I will guess that $X$ is the sample mean $(X_1+\cdots+X_9)/9$. Then $X$ has mean $1$ and variance $1/9$, so standard deviation $1/3$. The number $9$ is kind of small for CLT to be reliable, but it looks as if we are trying to find the probability that a normal of mean $1$ and standard deviation $1/3$ differs from the mean by less than $0.6$.

Comment: The rest depends on whether you are using tables or software. If it is tables, I would find the probability $p$ that the standard normal is bigger than $1.8$. Then our answer is $1-2p$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming @AndreNicholas has interpreted the problem correctly, an interpretation that makes sense to me, you want to find the
$P(0.4 \le \bar X \le 1.6),$ where $\bar X$ is the mean of
$n = 9$ iid $X_i \sim Exp(1).$

The precise distribution of the mean is given by $\bar X \sim Gamma(shape=9, rate=9).$ This distribution has mean 1, variance 1/9
and SD 1/3. From R statistical software, one finds the
exact value of $P(0.4 \le \bar X \le 1.6) = 0.9374$ (to four places).

```
 diff(pgamma(c(.4,1.6), 9, 9))
 ## 0.9374498
```

I believe $n = 9$ is much too small for a good normal approximation
via the Central Limit Theorem for many probabilities involving your $\bar X$. Nevertheless, that approximation happens  to work pretty well for this particular case, yielding 0.9281 (to four places).

```
 diff(pnorm(c(.4,1.6), 1, 1/3))
 ## 0.9281394
```

The figure below illustrates these computations.

[image]